# Estadísticas Winter Bash 2016

Tags: discusión

Una vez terminado el evento **Winter Bash 2016** sería interesante contar con algunas estadísticas del evento como se ha hecho en la versión inglesa del sitio
http://stackoverflow.blog/2017/01/say-farewell-to-winter-bash-2016/?cb=1

Estadísticas como: Usuarios con mayor cantidad de sombreros obtenidos, total de sombreros obtenidos en todo el sitio, usuarios con más sombreros secretos, entre otros, aquí se puede compartir ideas de que estadísticas serian interesantes visualizar.

Comment: Creo los datos no están en http://data.stackexchange.com, por lo que lo único que podríamos aportar serían capturas de pantalla o lo que se pueda sacar de la página [Stack Overflow en español dentro del Winter Bash](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/es.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Lo que sí debe decirse bien alto es que [Mariano](http://es.stackoverflow.com/users/127/mariano) ganó con muchísima diferencia, ¡consiguió 34 de los 41 sombreros!

Comment: [36 en total](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network) :-P (34 en SOes + 2 que eran exclusivos de SO).

Answer (score 6):

Las estadísticas de WB16 para SOes están publicadas en

#### http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/es.stackoverflow.com

<sup>(aunque no sé por cuánto tiempo)</sup>

---

#### Tabla de posiciones en SOes (Top 20)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
<sup>* en caso de empate, no hay otro criterio de ordenación: es arbitrario</sup>

Comment: sin mi sombrero "This Is Fine" me siento al descubierto.

Comment: Uno de los más difíciles. Sólo [958 usuarios lo obtuvieron](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289669/304899)... Faltan 11 meses para WB17, pero una de las propuestas más votadas pide que [sean sombreros, y no máscaras](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289360/304899).

Comment: ¡Volvió @Rene! https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/this-is-fine ;-)

Comment: hace unos dias estaba pensando en el winter bash