# La cronología de Stack Overflow en Español contada por medio de preguntas

Tags: discusión

## ¿Cuáles son los hilos que señalan los momentos más significativos de SOes?

Las culturas alrededor del mundo tienen diversas formas se señalar los momentos más significativos, a través de monumentos, tótems, milestones. Siendo este un sitio de preguntas y respuestas ¿cuáles hilos consideras que son los más representativos?

Comment: Deberías estructurar mejor la publicación y poner lo que es pregunta en la pregunta en sí, y lo que es respuesta en una respuesta.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro No sé a que te refieres con estructurar mejor, pero lo de pasar la respuesta a una respuesta, lo acabo de hacer.

Comment: En lugar de la palabra *hilos*, yo utilizaría *hitos*, refiriéndome a un hecho relevante. No todos los eventos importantes han sido hilos o preguntas :)

Comment: @Flxtr: Pero en ese caso ya no sería "contada por medio de preguntas" ¿verdad?

Comment: @Rubén exacto :) no todos los eventos sobresalientes representan un hilo.

Comment: @Flxtr: Estoy de acuerdo, pero en el caso de esta pregunta, es sobre hilos. Me pregunto si "alguien" quisiera iniciar un hllo sobre hitos, tal vez uno que está de viaje de Ciudad de México a Monterrey :P

Comment: @Rubén Jajaja xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Introducción

Cada sitio en la red de Stack Exchange es especial, pero para nosotros lo es de forma particular. Una de las cosas que lo hace especial, es que a diferencia de otros sitios en **beta pública**, este sitio tiene un diseño propio desde muy temprano. A continuación una lista de lo que podrían ser las publicaciones mas representativas de diferentes momentos desde que se propuso el sitio a la fecha, en orden cronológico inverso.

## Mayo 2017

- Graduación día 17: en el blog, [¡Stack Overflow en español se gradúa hoy!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/17/stack-overflow-en-espanol-se-gradua-hoy/)
- [Últimas estadisticas del sitio antes de la graduación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1978/65)

## Al año y un mes, enero 2017

- [Webcasts 2017 - ¿cómo y por qué? — ¡Fechas!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1337/)
- [Objetivos del 2017 - Primera Parte (1)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1275/)
- [Objetivos del 2017 - Segunda Parte (2)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1314/)

## Al año, diciembre de 2016

- [Estadísticas Winter Bash 2016](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1272/)

## A los 11 meses, noviembre de 2016

- [Esta pregunta fue cerrada pero a la vez fue la pregunta más visitada el mes de octubre. ¿La reabrimos?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1055/esta-pregunta-fue-cerrada-pero-a-la-vez-fue-la-pregunta-m%C3%A1s-visitada-el-mes-de-o)

## A un mes de beta pública, enero 2016

- [Webcasts 2016 - ¿cómo y por qué? -- ¡Fechas!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419/)
- [Un mes de beta publico - ¿ahora qué?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374/)

## Beta pública, diciembre 2015 - mayo 2017

El público en general puede participar.

- [Diciembre 15: Se abre Stack Overflow en Español al Público](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258/)
- http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810?phase=beta

## Beta privada, octubre - diciembre 2015

Se prepara el sitio. En el caso de Stack Overflow en Español esto implicó la traducción de la interfaz así como de los principales artículos de ayuda, la publicación de preguntas y respuestas que servirán de ejemplo para los usuarios que se integren en la siguiente etapa.

- [¡Bienvenidos a este su sitio!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/146/)
- [Presentamos Winter Bash 2015](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256/)
- The [“Stack Overflow in Spanish” Project is Underway!](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21519/the-stack-overflow-in-spanish-project-is-underway)

## Compromiso, noviembre 2012 - octubre 2015

Una vez definido el alcance del sitio, las personas pueden comprometerse a apoyar el sitio en la fase beta privada cuando este sea lanzado.

- http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810?phase=commitment

## Definición, agosto - noviembre 2012

La propuesta del sitio se realiza en un sitio especial llamado Area 51. Se publican preguntas tentativas y se votan si son o no pertinentes para el sitio con la finalidad de definir el alcance del mismo.

- http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810?phase=definition

Comment: Añadí la información sobre la graduación: fechas y la entrada de blog de JuanM.

Comment: Gracias fedorqui. He vuelvo la publicación wiki de comunidad :)